# What does this T_IF error mean?

Tags: php, parsing

```
<?php
$to = "service@mysite.no";
$subject = "Reparasjon av " . $_REQUEST['type'] . " fra mysite.no";
$types = if(!empty($_REQUEST['type'])) {echo($_REQUEST['type'] . ". ");};
$reps = if(!empty($_REQUEST['rep'])) {echo($_REQUEST['rep']);};
$message =  $types . . $reps . "\n\nKommentarer:\n" . $_REQUEST['kommentarer'] . "\n\nFra:\n" . $_REQUEST['navn'] . "\nTelefon: " . $_REQUEST['telefon'] . "\nEmail: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\nBosted: " . $_REQUEST['bosted'];
$headers =  "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
if (mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers)) {
   header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.no/' );
  } else {
   header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.no/' );
  }
?>
```

It says there's a T_IF error in line 4. What's the problem?

Comment: It means "found `Token_IF` (`if`) where `if` is not valid". See therin's answer for why it is not a valid expression (only expressions can be used as rvalues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `if` there, it's a syntax error. Technically `if` is a statement, not an expression. That means you can't use it in an assignment like `$types = if (...)`.

Answer (score 2):

`if()` is a language construct, not a function. It does not return anything, and cannot be assigned to a variable.

```
$types = if(!empty($_REQUEST['type'])) {echo($_REQUEST['type'] . ". ");};
^^^^^^^^--- not allowed
```

Try:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['type']) {
   $types = $_REQUEST['type'];
}
```

As well, echo cause direct output to the client. it does not "return" anything that can be assigned.

Comment: Better would have been "if() is a statement, not an expression" (as in PHP some language constructs like include, print or eval do return something.)

Answer (score 1):

An IF statement does not return a value, so assigning it to a variable does nothing (and might even be causing your error!) Take off the semicolons from the end of the if statements, too.

Try this:

```
if (!empty($some_variable)) {
  $my_var = $some_variable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can see is in line `$message = …` there is a double concatenation operator, which is clearly a syntax error. Should be (and should use escaped output):

```
$message =  $types . $reps . "\n\nKommentarer:\n" . $_REQUEST['kommentarer'] . "\n\nFra:\n" . $_REQUEST['navn'] . "\nTelefon: " . $_REQUEST['telefon'] . "\nEmail: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\nBosted: " . $_REQUEST['bosted'];
```

ps. god, so much wrong with this code (still no escaping/sanitazation in place) …

```
<?php
$to = "service@mysite.no";
$subject = "Reparasjon av " . $_REQUEST['type'] . " fra mysite.no";
$types = !empty($_REQUEST['type']) ? $_REQUEST['type'] . ". " : '';
$reps = !empty($_REQUEST['rep']) ? $_REQUEST['rep'] : '' ;
$message =  $types . $reps . "\n\nKommentarer:\n" . $_REQUEST['kommentarer'] . "\n\nFra:\n" . $_REQUEST['navn'] . "\nTelefon: " . $_REQUEST['telefon'] . "\nEmail: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\nBosted: " . $_REQUEST['bosted'];
$headers =  "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
if (mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $headers)) {
   header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.no/' );
  } else {
   header( 'Location: http://www.mysite.no/' );
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines

```
$types = if(!empty($_REQUEST['type'])) {echo($_REQUEST['type'] . ". ");};
$reps = if(!empty($_REQUEST['rep'])) {echo($_REQUEST['rep']);};
```

are invalid. `if` statements are not expressions in PHP; they don't evaluate to a value which can be assigned to a variable. You're also not "returning" anything from the `if`; `echo` writes to the screen, it doesn't "echo" a value out of an if statement to the calling scope.

You want the following:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['type'])) {
  $types = ($_REQUEST['type'] . ". ");
}
```